# Paypal IPN and payer email

Tags: parameters, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using Paypal to receive donations, and IPN to track the information that comes through. I'm new to all. Under what conditions will the payer_email not be transmitted from the IPN? At one end of the spectrum, Will the parameters *always* contain payer_email because this it required? At the other end of the spectrum, will the payer_email usually be unavailable because the payer chooses to keep it private?

Answer (score 1):

In most all cases you'll get a payer_email included.  The only time you might not is when you get an IPN for a dispute, but I think even that would include it.

You can refer to [PayPal's IPN Variables list](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) for more details on what you should expect with each IPN type.